# Given an IBuildDetail instance how can I figure out what local path was used to build the code?

Tags: tfs

I can access it like this:

```
BuildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings.First(m => m.LocalItem != null).LocalItem
```

It gives me the local path of the first active mapping, I am OK with it. The problem is that it returns the current local path, not the historic one and this is a problem for me.

How can I extract the actual local path used at the moment when the build was in progress?

I am using TFS 2013.

**EDIT 1**

Let me give an example.

Given:

1. Build definition `BuildDef` mapping to folder `D:\TFS` on certain agent

Scenario:

1. Run a build of `BuildDef`. Let it be `Build1`
2. Change the mapping of `BuildDef` to point to `C:\TFS` on the same agent
3. Run a build of `BuildDef`. Let it be `Build2`

Now, suppose I have the `IBuildDetail` describing the build `Build1`. I am looking for a way to extract what was the mapping at the time of the build. Right now, the only way I know of is to inspect the

```
IBuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings
```

collection, but it returns the current mapping as stored right now in the build definition, which points to `C:\TFS`. Now that is not what I am looking for, after all `Build1` was working on `D:\TFS`.

**EDIT 2**

I am using the following code to fetch the builds:

```
var spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(projectName);
spec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
spec.MinFinishTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(minFinishTimeOfs);
spec.MaxFinishTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(maxFinishTimeOfs);
if (reason != null)
{
    spec.Reason = reason.Value;
}
if (status != null)
{
    spec.Status = status.Value;
}
if (withBuildErrors || errorKeywords != null)
{
    spec.InformationTypes = new[] { InformationTypes.BuildError };
}
var buildDetails = buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec).Builds;
if (errorKeywords != null)
{
    buildDetails = buildDetails.Where(res => InformationNodeConverters.GetBuildErrors(res).Any(e => errorKeywords.Any(keyword => e.Message.Contains(keyword)))).ToArray();
}
if (controllerName != null)
{
    buildDetails = buildDetails.Where(res => string.Equals(GetBuildControllerName(res), controllerName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**IBuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings** is return the current mappings for the build definition, it does not change base on the build you query.

The alternative way I use is get the local path of the solution file during the build via **IBuildDetail.Information.GetNode(13).Fields["LocalPath"]**. This will return the entire path to the solution file but it does not change after the build definition is updated. The result is as following (Same definition with different mapping):
[image]

Code for your reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace BuildAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string project = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(project));
            IBuildServer ibs = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();
            var builds = ibs.QueryBuilds("TeamProjectName");
            foreach (IBuildDetail ibd in builds)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("************************************************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("Local Path:" + ibd.Information.GetNode(13).Fields["LocalPath"]);
                Console.WriteLine("************************************************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("Build Definition Name:" + ibd.BuildDefinition.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("************************************************************************");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: In my case `Information.GetNode(13)` returns `null`.

Comment: @mark Then you may need to list out all the nodes in IBuildDetail.Information to see which node include the local path information.

Comment: Checked `GetNode(i)` for i from 0 to 20. All return `null`. I suppose I can continue checking, but this approach does not seem very robust.

Comment: That's strange. Node 1 to 20 should all include information.

Comment: Not necessarily. We use different code to fetch builds. I am using an `IBuildDetailSpec` object to specify which builds I want, you seem to fetch all the builds in the project. I cannot use your approach, because that would return too many builds. Please, see **EDIT 2** where I show the code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get build agent working directory. You can check [IBuildAgent.BuildDirectory Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildagent.builddirectory.aspx).

Comment: Our build definition does not use the build directory property of the build agent. The build template takes the local path of the first active mapping and works with it.